# struggling to find basis of range

Tags: linear-algebra

I have found the range of a linear transformation restricted to the generalized eigenspace of $T$
$T(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5)=\{(z_1,z_1-z_2-z_5,z_1-z_2-z_5,-z_5,-z_1+z_2+z_5):z_1,z_2,z_5 \in\mathbb{C}\}$
to be

$\text{rangeT}|_{G(0,T)}=\{(0,-z_2-z_5,-z_2-z_5,-z_5,z_2+z_5):z_2,z_5 \in \mathbb{C}\}$

what would be a basis of this vector space $\text{rangeT}|_{G(0,T)}$?

Would it be $(0,-1,-1,0,1),(0,-1,-1,-1,1)$ or $(0,-1,-1,0,1),(0,0,0,-1,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have 
\begin{align*}
(0,-z_2-z_5,-z_2-z_5,-z_5,z_2+z_5) = z_2(0,-1,-1,0,1)+z_5(0,-1,-1,-1,1),
\end{align*}
so your first choice works.

Comment: would both choices actually work since $(0,0,0,1,0)$ is in the span of the basis vectors in the first list?

Comment: Yes sure, I guess the first choice is just the most immediate.